# In a video, it promised journey times of 12 minutes between the two cities

Tags: pronouns

> In a video, **it** promised journey times of 12 minutes between the two cities. [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-37908915)

The pronoun *it* take the place of what? Who did promise?

- The video.
- Someone showed in the vedio.
- Or it's *Dummy it*.

Comment: @Laure the source was added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It" is defined in the preceding sentence: **the firm** (Hyperloop One).

It cannot represent the video, the subject would not be repeated but just "the video promised...". "Someone"  would be *he* or *she* or *they*.

The journalist could have also chosen to use *they* instead of *it*.

> In a video, [they] promised journey times of 12 minutes between the two cities.

thus pointing to the people in the firm who made the video, and not to the firm as a whole.